# Move .local folder outside home on a running machine

Tags: linux, pop-os, xdg

I've been on a mission to keep my home partition lean and easily backable until recently when I came across a bloated `.local` subdir much to my annoyance.

I tried moving it out to a different partition and symlinking back to home but a bunch of applications crashed, because they were obviously using this. I next tried doing the same from recovery but the system just won't login after that unless I move the subdir back.

I'm not sure what's happening here. Why should the system depend on real files? A symlink should be transparent to applications. And what steps can I follow to move `.local` dir elsewhere on a running machine?